# JPA Transaction scope

Tags: jpa, transactions

I am having a container-managed transaction and three Enterprise Java Beans. The first bean is a link between other two EJBS:

```
@Stateful
public class UserManagement 
{
    @EJB
    UsersFacade usersFacade;
    @EJB
    UserDetailsFacade userDetailsFacade;

    public void addUser()
    {
       //Point 1
       UserEntity ue = new UserEntity();
       UserDetailsEntity ude = new UserDetailsEntity();
       ue.setDetails(ude);
       userFacade.create(ue); //Wrapper around EntityManager.persist method
       userDetailsFacade.create(ude); Wrapper around EntityManager.persist method
       //Point 2
    }
}
```

Question: Will all of the operations within addUser() be performed in single transactions (userFacade.create and userDetailsFacade.create ) ?
Does @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) mean that transaction starts togheter with addUser method and it includes all methods executed from within addUser method. And the transaction ends in the moment when addUser ends?

And how to make sure that addUser will have its own private transaction (which will include methods from within it) and that the transaction will be commited when the method terminates. ?